# Definition of a calorie - confusion

Tags: energy, units, definition

Wikipedia defines a calorie as

> the (approximate) amount of energy needed to raise the temperature of 1 gram of water by 1 degree Celsius at a pressure of 1 atmosphere.

Is it the case then that, for example, $x$ calories is the (approximate) amount of energy needed to raise the temperature of 1 gram of water by $x$ degree Celsius at a pressure of 1 atmosphere, or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: And at 20 C. Or 15 C in a different definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.thermexcel.com/english/tables/unitnext.htm,

> The general standard, it is the quantity of heat necessary to raise 1°C the temperature of 1 gram of water of 14.5 to 15.5°C under the normal atmospheric pressure.

As you mentioned, it is correct that $x$ calories of energy is needed to raise the temperature of 1 gram of water by $x$ degree Celsius at a pressure of 1 atmosphere.  This is also true if there are $x$ grams of water and the other variables stay at 1.  The same is true for atmospheric pressure too.

Comment: The calorie is also case-sensitive.  One Calorie is equal to one kilocalorie.